# Why does my pointer have a different value after I've dereferenced it in main vs when Ive dereferenced it within my own custom function?

Tags: c++, pointers

Why does my pointer have a different value after I've dereferenced it in main vs when Ive dereferenced  it within my own custom function?

It's probably something really simple but I can't figure it out. 
Here is the code below:

```
int *addNumbers(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int no1 = 1;
    int no2 = 3;
    int no3 = 8;
    int *answer = &no3;

answer = addNumbers(no1, no2);
std::cout << answer << std::endl;
std::cout << *answer << std::endl;

/* Why does this second cout line not give the same 
answer as the second cout statement
 in the addNumbers function? */

}

int *addNumbers(int a, int b)
{
    int *resultPntr;
    int result = a+b;
    resultPntr = &result;
    std::cout << resultPntr << std::endl;
    std::cout << *resultPntr << std::endl;
    return resultPntr;
}
```

I thought dereferencing resultPntr and answer would give the same value??

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local automatic variable. Dereferencing that pointer is undefined.

Comment: Is that a dragon coming out of your nostrils?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to `result` that is a local variable in `addNumbers`.
Local variable *lives* into his scope. So when you exit from `addNumbers` will be destroyed!

If you want to get the same result you need to do this:

```
int *addNumbers(int a, int b)
{
    int *resultPntr = new int;
    *resultPntr = a+b;
    std::cout << resultPntr << std::endl;
    std::cout << *resultPntr << std::endl;
    return resultPntr;
}
```

N.B. When you declare new variables with *`new`*, you need to `delete` it at last.

Comment: Might be worthing mentioning that the pointer needs to be `delete`d at last, or use smart pointers instead.

Comment: @songyuanyao thank's for your reminder

Answer (score 8):

`addNumbers()` is trying to return a pointer pointing to local variable `result`, which will be destroyed when get out of the function. Then `answer` in `main()` is just a dangled pointer, dereferencing on it is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), means anything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This line in `addNumbers()` function:

```
int result = a+b;
resultPntr = &result;
std::cout << *resultPntr << std::endl;
...
return resultPntr;
```

Displays the value of the `result` variable which is a local variable. Since `result` is a local variable its scope is with in the function it is defined which means it will no longer be available when your function returns to `main`.

In `main`:

```
answer = addNumbers(no1, no2);
std::cout << *answer << std::endl;
```

Is trying to deference the returned pointer from `addNumbers()` function. The returned pointer contain a memory location that was once occupied by the `result` local variable in your `addNumbers()` function which is now destroyed,as a result of returning to `main`, and hence the result of such an operation is **undefined** and you can't relay on it to give you the value you get when you were inside `addNumbers()`.

This is one good reason why you should not return a reference or pointer of a local variable from a function.